# Plotting a graph with its confidence interval in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, confidence-interval

I have a model that gives me a prediction together with the error estimate.

So we have X for the time, Y for the prediction and E for the error.

I would like to plot the prediction and the confidence interval.

The image below shows the type of result I would like to achieve:

[image: Graph with surface area]

Don't bother about the vertical stripes and the dashed line.

The graph has a plot that can be made as following:

```
plot( X, Y, type = 'l', col='red')
```

Then there is a 50% confidence interval that is as follow
[Y+E, Y-E]

So I could add two lines using:

```
lines(X, Y+E)
lines(X, Y-E)
```

But instead I would like to color the area between those lines (and preferably using basic R).

Is this possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: Plot a `polygon` or switch to `ggplot2`.

Comment: As Axeman already suggested you can use `polygon` from the base package, e.g.,  `polygon(c(X, rev(X)), c(Y-E, rev(Y+E)))`.

Comment: I have searched for quite a while, maybe I did not have the proper vocabulary. But the polygon approach will do the trick.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing this other post.